# Intellij 2023 IDE: Always show the Menu Bar at top

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I downloaded the new IntelliJ Java for 2023.

To see the menu Bar. I need to do additional click. First click the button in Green box below, and then I can see the File menu. I want it like the original, where menu is Always showing. How can this be done ?

**Step 1:**

[image]

**Step 2:**

[image]

Its slightly cumbersome to do additional click everytime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ctrl + Shift + A to show actions, then type "Main Menu" and check it

[image: Main Menu toggle]

Also,

b) go to "Settings | Appearance & Behavior | New UI" and enable the "Show main menu" in a separate toolbar option.

c) Alternatively, go to "View | Appearance" and enable "Main Menu as Separate Toolbar".

Comment: That means you can only have two bars at the same time, not the main menu as part of the existing new UI toolbar? Two is overkill, but the reductive bar hides too much.